# why the * in front of the object name

Tags: objective-c

I'm just starting to look at some objective-c stuff and was wondering what some of the content in this line of code means:

```
MyClass *myObject = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

It's a bit confusing why I need the asterisk. I understand that this is a pointer, but I've been reading some blogs that say this signifies that myObject is an object. What is the right way to think about that "*"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The asterisk simply indicates that the myObject variable is a pointer, similar to its c counterpart.

Objective c objects are allocated on the heap, hence [[MyClass alloc] init] returns a pointer to a MyClass object. Hence, you need to declare a pointer variable to store the pointer.

Comment: why do I need a pointer to an object? Why not just the object itself like java

Comment: I don't have an official explanation here, my guess it's because the Objective C language is based on C. In C at times it is good to differentiate between objects on the heap and object on the stack.

Comment: Apple decided to allocate ALL Obj-C objects on the heap, hence the pointer paradigm. It is a compiler error to attempt to allocate an Obj-C object as an automatic variable.

Comment: @cfarm54: Java is a high-level object-oriented language where objects are first-class citizens. Under the hood Java of course allocates objects on a heap and an object "value" is in fact a "pointer to a heap block" - but you don't get to see this, just as you don't get to see the sign, magnitude and mantissa parts of floating point numbers. C is a high-level assembler which does not hide the implementation details from you, if something is implemented with a pointer you see the pointer, but the parts of floating point numbers are still abstracted away!

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally in C/C++, the * means "pointer to type of an object". So * int is "a pointer to an integer". So * MyObject is a type of "a pointer to a type of MyObject".